# How best to triangulate a 5-point star polygon?

Tags: polygon, triangulation

I've implemented the "ear-splitting" triangulation method for simple polygons.  In testing it out, I see it crashes on the test case of a symmetrical 5-point star.
I think I understand why this polygon is "tricky" -- because it contains edges that are collinear....an ear-shaving diagonal which the algorithm chooses based on starting with a convex vertex (one of the 5 points), then inspecting the diagonal for no "X" edge intersections, and for no vertices intruding into the ear triangle) will blindly assign a diagonal which is collinear with 2 existing edges.  After removing the ear's external vertex, the remaining polygon will no longer be "simple" -- it will have vertices having a straight angle (180 deg.), a violation of the simple polygon contract.

I'm chagrined that I've proven that ear-splitting faces this failure case.  I thought from the literature that it was a general-purpose method (applicable to all simple polygons).  Are those "inductive proofs" you find repeated everywhere overstated?

Has anyone successfully modified an ear-splitting triangulation method to handle the 5-point star?

Answer (score 0):

Random Perturbation of Collinear Edge Endpoints

The "ear-splitting" triangulation algo suffers from a breakdown in the case of polygons which have edges that are collinear.  As you can see in the 5-point star, all the edges have this problem.

A simple "patch" can rescue the "ear-splitting" triangulation algo:

1) Before beginning the triangulation, inspect the polygon's edge list (as LineSegs) for any pair of edges that share the same 2D extended line.  Apply a tiny random perturbation to both endpoints of any such edge, (e.g., in the range -0.001..+0.001.)  Save the original locations of these vertices, so they can be restored after the triangulation.

2) Now you can run ear-split triangulation, having removed the ill-conditioned situation of collinear edges.

3) Undo the perturbations you applied to the vertices.

I've tested this approach, and it works fine.  It might seem a bit of a hack, but it's by far the easiest way to rescue the ear-split triangulation from its most noticeable flaw.  The random perturbations want to be tiny compared to location coordinates in your app, but huge compared to the finite math EPSILON you're using to compare real-numbers for equal.